# Replace Navigator 1.0 with Navigator 2.0 to (Android Only)

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

So in my opinion Navigator 2.0 makes more sense when running the application on the web. I have an application that I am implementing under construction is an inventory system for a store. It is being developed to be used by employees and run only on Android. The application so far has 32 screens. So would the new Navigator 2.0 offer me some optimization or improvement in the application if I decide to change from an imperative navigation?

By default the new navigation system is complex, but that complexity is benefited when we have an application that requires history (Web), something that an android application does not really need. If I am wrong please deny me and show the right way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're more or less right that the new Navigator 2.0 shows its main benefits when using your Flutter app on web (e.g. history stack).

Personally, I use Navigator 2.0 also in my mobile applications. However, I don't migrate old applications developed before Flutter 1.22. Usually the cost of migration would be higher than impact of Navigator 2.0 advantages. Sometimes you can think about using Navigator 2.0 in some selected areas of your app e.g. tab navigation or in some specific flow (e.g. ecommerce purchase).

One main benefit in mobile apps that is really helpful when thinking about migrating to Navigator 2.0 is deep links handling. For instance if you need to open some specific screen from push notifications or drastically change your navigation stack in response to events (e.g. after sign up).

In the simplest case you can just use Page API that doesn't require setting up RouterDelegate, RouteInformationParser and RouteInformationProvider. You can find some of my [Navigator 2.0 samples here](https://github.com/orestesgaolin/navigator_20_example).